# Advice on Indexing nvarchar columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to building indexes and have a question about best practice.

At its core I have the following 3 tables:

**Table A**

~ 100,000 rows

For a given item e.g. product, some information on what it is

```
  ArticleId [int] (PK)
  ... some static info columns
```

**Table B**

~ 100,000 * `K` rows, where `K` will increase as we update table B every few months. Contains variables that aren't fixed, but can change each iteration.

```
  UploadId [int] -- one for each K iterations
  ArticleId [int] (FK on table A)
  GroupingA [nvarchar](255)
  GroupingB [nvarchar](255)
```

**Table C**

~ 50 million rows, sales data

```
  ArticleId [int] (FK on table A)
  Date [date]
  Sales [int]
```

As the tables are large, I am wary that we may need some good quality indexes or else query performance will suffer. I have read it's not a good idea to use clustered index's on character types.

One of the main queries is to join B & C and aggregate data up to the levels of `GroupingA` & `GroupingB` as so:

```
SELECT 
    C.[Date],
    B.[GroupingA], B.[GroupingB],
    SUM(C.Sales) AS Sales
FROM 
    C
INNER JOIN
    B ON C.[ArticleId] = B.[ArticleId]
WHERE
    B.Upload.Id = 1 -- example
GROUP BY
    C.[Date], B.[GroupingA], B.[GroupingB]
```

For table C I have made a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ... on (Date, ArticleId)`. For table B I was planning on making one for `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ... on (UploadId, ArticleId)`.

Is it a good idea to put a clustered or nonclustered index on `B.[GroupingA], B.[GroupingB]` even though they are characters? They will be used heavily in the groupings, so I'm worried by not indexing them it could be really slow. Should I be turning them in to lookup's as well with their own made up `identity()` ids? Any ideas or links would be great :)

Also, we may have more groupings in the future e.g. GroupingC, .. etc. Thanks in advance!

My SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) 
          on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 17134: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: As an idea: store results of "the query" in a table, that you can reference elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Indexes on those columns are not going to help your query.  Your aggregation is combining columns from two tables, so you cannot improve it with indexing.

You can index `B(upload_id, article_id)` and `c(article_id, date, sales)`.

You might be able to phrase the query as:

```
select C.[Date], B.[GroupingA], B.[GroupingB]
       sum(C.Sales) as Sales
from (select c.articleid, sum(c.sales) as sales
      from c
      group by c.articleid
     ) c join b
     b
     on C.ArticleId = B.ArticleId
where B.Upload_Id = 1 -- example
group by C.[Date], B.[GroupingA], B.[GroupingB];
```

However, two levels of aggregation will not help, unless the inner one significantly reduces the volume of data and can make use of an index on `c(articleid, sales)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the query. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit, to see if anyone else has other ideas